# MySQL Master/Slave with Castle Activerecord

Tags: mysql, castle-activerecord

I have an existing web application using Castle Activerecord to interact with a single MySQL database. The Database has recently been reconfigured to replicate to a number of Slaves.

How do you configure Castle Activerecord to direct writes to the MySQL Master and reads to the MySQL Slaves or are there other ways of achieving Master/Slave operation transparently in this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never done this, but I think this kind of things are better handled at the DB-driver level. Indeed, [Connector/J has a specific ReplicationDriver](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-replication-connection.html) for this purpose. The [Connector/NET documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-connection-options.html) has a rather vague reference to replication:

> Host, Server, Data Source, DataSource, Address, Addr, Network Address:
>
> The name or network address of the
> instance of MySQL to which to connect.
> Multiple hosts can be specified
> separated by &. This can be useful
> where multiple MySQL servers are
> configured for replication and you are
> not concerned about the precise server
> you are connecting to. No attempt is
> made by the provider to synchronize
> writes to the database so care should
> be taken when using this option. In
> Unix environment with Mono, this can
> be a fully qualified path to MySQL
> socket file name. With this
> configuration, the Unix socket will be
> used instead of TCP/IP socket.
> Currently only a single socket name
> can be given so accessing MySQL in a
> replicated environment using Unix
> sockets is not currently supported.

Comment: Completely agree, this is definitely a task a developer would want handled transparently if possible. I'll take a look at your suggestion in a separate project that uses a Master-Master configuration which could probably benefit. Thank you very much for the pointer :)